# Footable Memory Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

Installing this plugin. The documents say:

```
 * Disabled by default, to enable add the following section to the footable
 * options:
 *
 *   $('#table').footable({
 *     memory: {
 *       enabled: true
 *     }
 *   });
```

Where the heck is this section to edit this code to enable? I have been all over the repository and documentation and I still don't have a clue.

This should be an easy one if someone could just point to where it goes...

Thanks!

Comment: That would be wherever you're instantiating the plugin

Comment: You all are quick... all I did was go make a sandwich. I had tried that but didn't change the name to my table. ;(

Comment: sorry one more question... I thought this was doable with inserted rows? but when I refresh I loss them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select your table with `$('#your-table-id')` and add the footable plugin to it using to code shown in your question.
You should add the code before your closing bode tag, like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#your-table-id').footable({
          memory: {
            enabled: true
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

I assume you have the jQuery Framework and the plugin already included into your page.

Comment: Thanks Michael that did it... I have garlic.js installed to cover my form inputs. I was adding this plugin for my inserted rows. I had tried this way before but didn't change the table name.  Do you if this plugin can support inserted rows?

Comment: I don't know this plugin, it's best if you test this. If you need more help, it would be helpful if you post your related HTML and javascript code.